# Wordpress change color background of active and hover li

Tags: html, css, wordpress

`Navbar > li > a` is not working in my wordpress. I tried to use `#nav > li > a` to change the color and background of its `li`.
And my main problem is I cannot change the class active of my home link, can someone post a sample on how to change this?

code is here thank you very much!

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" id="nav">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
                  data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
              <img src="http://conlinscoffee.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/conlins_logo.png" 
                   class=" img-responsive" alt="logo">
          </a>
        </div>  
        <?php
        wp_nav_menu( array(
            'menu'              => 'primary',
            'theme_location'    => 'primary',
            'depth'             => 2,
            'container'         => 'div',
            'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
            'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
            'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
            'fallback_cb'       => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
            'walker'            => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker())
            );
        ?>
        <div class="pull-right" id="searchbar">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'top-menu' ); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the HTML that actually gets generated after it runs through wordpress?

Comment: Yes please, or the live site and we can just inspect element from there

Comment: i run this work in live, conlinscoffee.com i created my own theme for the first time

Comment: It seems like `current-menu-item` class is missing in your menu which is dynamically added by Wordpress and by using which we can also add our respective css for current active menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following CSS for this

```
#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 li > a {
  // your css here
}


#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 li:hover > a,
#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 li.current_page_item > a {
  // your css here
}
```

**Or you can use**

```
#menu-main_menu > li > a {
    color: #fff;
}

#menu-main_menu > li:hover > a, 
#menu-main_menu > li.current_page_item > a {
    color: #c42027;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: yes! it works but i want also to change my active home link to red

Comment: @France we already write active link CSS code in answer & as we can see it's working fine in your site

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li>a:hover{color:#fff;}
```

Comment: Not working ? Can you please include the full code why it is not working this is strange

Comment: you can visit my site conlinscoffee.com

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
.className li:hover{
 //set background color for li here.
 //background-color: #fff;
 }

.className li:hover > a{
 //set color for the text here.
 //you can set the color of text like here.
 color: #000 !important; //you can use any color, just use !important keyword for replacing inherited colors.
 }
```

//sorry i dont have enough reputations for commenting.

Comment: .navbar li:hover { background: #fff;  } this is working but in .navbar li:hover > a is not working, i want to change also the text of my menu to white instead of its inheritted color

Comment: .navbar li:hover > a { color: #000; } NOTE: if you have background color #fff and text color #fff (both are same color) you can't see the text.

Answer (score 0):

Don't change the li's itself.

Use this selector

`.navbar-nav > li > a {
    background: white;
}`

White background is a sample

For active, just add :active like so

`.navbar-nav > li > a:active {
    background: white;
}`

You can also add important like this if still not working

`.navbar-nav > li > a:active {
    background: white!important;
}`

Answer (score 0):

There is not problem with the current CSS for the menu items in your website. 
The problem you are experiencing is being caused by your nav tag. Specifically have a look at this line of code in your style.css:

```
#nav {
    background: #c42027;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
}
```

The margin-bottom rule is causing the div right after the nav element to go up and cover the list items, thus preventing them from working with hover. Change the #nav margin-bottom to 0 and the problem will be resolved.

Comment: i remove all the margins now, since i will remove my carousel and change it to carousel plugins for easy use